# Deserialize into object from not nested xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

Imaging an XML-file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<treffer>
    <prod_internid>123456789</prod_internid>
    <md_nr>123123</md_nr>
    <md_mart_id>4</md_mart_id>
    <md_mtyp_nr>9876</md_mtyp_nr>
    <mra_th>
        <ie_th_pth>-1</ie_th_pth>
        <ie_th_ea_bez>Fehler: Keine Angabe</ie_th_ea_bez>
    </mra_th>
</treffer>
```

As you can see, there are three tags with `<md_XY></md_XY>`.
I want to deserialize them into an object  that looks like this:

```
public class DeMedienXmlDto
{
    [XmlElement("md_nr")]
    public int MedienNr { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("md_mart_id")]
    public int MedienArtId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("md_mtyp_nr")]
    public string MedienTypId { get; set; }
}
```

But this should be a property of the whole deserialized object:

```
[XmlRoot("treffer")]
public class DeAnalyseArtikelXmlDto
{
    [XmlElement("prod_internid")]
    public long ArtikelId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("treffer")]
    public DeMedienXmlDto Medium { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("mra_th")]
    public List<DeThemenXmlDto> Themen { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried annotating the `Medium` property with `[XmlElement("treffer")]` since the tags are childs of `<treffer>` but that didn't work...

Deserializing the `<mra_th>...</mra_th>` works since I can annotate the list with the grouped tag but I don't have such a tag for `<md...>`.

- How can I achieve this?

My xml deserializer looks like this:

```
public class XmlDeserializer : IXmlDeserializer
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(string xmlFilename)
    {
        var returnObject = default(T);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename)) return default(T);

        try
        {
            var xmlStream = new StreamReader(xmlFilename);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            LogHelper.LogError($"Das XML-File {xmlFilename} konnte nicht deserialisiert werden: {exception.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit (to clarify):**

I want the following tags deserialized into an object of type `DeMedienXmlDto`:

- `<md_nr>`
- `<md_mart_id>`
- `<md_mtyp_nr>`

Comment: As @Ondrej Tucny points out you cannot deserialize directly into the object structure you describe and will need to serialize to an object structure that matches the xml.  You can then manipulate your "treffer" object any way you like.  If you choose to put the different elements into different objects to work with, remember you will need to also reverse the process and put them back into the "treffer" before you serialize the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how `XmlSerializer` works. The class structure *must* correspond to structure of the XML in order to work automatically.

This:

```
[XmlElement("treffer")]
public DeMedienXmlDto Medium { get; set; }
```

doesn't work, because there is no *nested* `<treffer>` element. The `XmlElementAttribute` cannot denote the parent (surrounding) element.

The are two options how to solve your situation:

1. Use a separate set of classes for deserialization, and a separate set representing your DTO objects. You'd then need to create a mapping.
2. Implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=netframework-4.7.1) on `DeAnalyseArtikelXmlDto` and parse the inner XML yourself.